# Shorthand for Case in Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a class like the one below `ReportStatusConstants`. I use it to store the report status in a database in column.

What is the best way to convert it back to text when displaying in my view?
There must be a shorthand version of what I'm doing below?

currently I have something like this:

Razor:

```
@switch ((int)ViewBag.status)
{
    case 1:
        <p>Completed</p>
        break;
    case 0:
            <p>New</p>
        break;

}
```

My Class:

```
public class ReportStatusConstants
{

    public const int New = 0;
    public const int Complete = 1;
    public const int Rejected = 2;

}
```

here's a fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y0vYan

Comment: How about making `ReportStatusConstants` an enum, and then use DescriptionAttribute, or possibly just `.ToString()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum` for that,

```
public enum ReportStatusConstantsEnum
{
    New = 0,
    Complete = 1,
    Rejected = 2,
}
```

then in controller:

```
@ViewBag.status = ReportStatusConstantsEnum.New;
```

and in View:

```
@ViewBag.status.ToString()
```

here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vJowOd